# calling list() method over array of one element raises TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

calling list() method over pandas dataframe single row raises an error. For example,

```
 d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'col2': ['c', 'd', 'e']}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
 df
```

Now, the below is fine

```
list(df.loc[df.col1 == 'a']['col2'].values.squeeze())
```

but,

```
list(df.loc[df.col1 == 'b']['col2'].values.squeeze())
```

raises:

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

How to address this issue?

Comment: `list(df.loc[df.col1 == 'b']['col2'].values.squeeze())` should raise an error, not sure why it is working for you. But, your comment on `pd.Series.tolist()` worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) here.

```py
df.loc[df.col1 == 'a','col2'].tolist()

df.loc[df.col1 == 'b','col2'].tolist()
```

Comment: It more safe to do `df.loc[df.col1 == 'a','col2']` :-) upvoted ~

Comment: @YOBEN_S Yes, Agree. Thank you. I'll keep that in mind.